# Java Check if a new date range falls/crossovers between other date ranges

Tags: java, validation, date, compare

I need to determine if a date range is within/cross over other date ranges. For eg:

```
New start Date 1: 12/01/2015 (mm/dd/yyyy)
New start Date 2: 03/01/2016 --> Throw error message
```

---

```
New start Date 1: 12/01/2016
New start Date 2: 12/01/2017 --> Throw error message
```

Existing date ranges:

```
Existing 1: 01/01/2016 - 05/31/2016
Existing 2: 06/05/2017 - 10/31/2017
```

I should generate an error message if my new dates fall/crossover the existing dates. Here is my existing code (not working as expected):

```
for (Period p : periodList) {
    if (!(newPeriodStartDate.after(p.getExistingPeriodStartDate())) 
        && !(newPeriodStartDate.before(p.getExistingPeriodEndDate()))) {
            message = "The Period falls between an existing Period: "+p.periodName();
            break;
    }
    if (newPeriodEndDate.after(p.getExistingPeriodStartDate()) 
        && newPeriodEndDate.before(p.getExistingPeriodEndDate())) {
         if (message == null) {
            message = " The Period falls between an existing Period: "+p.getPeriodName();
         }
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Updated code (still not working). What am I missing:

```
if (!(newPeriodStartDate.getTime() <= p.getExistingPeriodEndDate().getTime())
                                        && (newPeriodEndDate.getTime() <= p.getExistingPeriodStartDate().getTime())) {
   ...
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is a duplicate question, but the answer to that question did not fix my issue. The blog post (http://baodad.blogspot.com/2014/06/date-range-overlap.html) helped me fix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938152/check-if-two-date-periods-overlap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: I think he was asking how to throw and exception

Comment: @sbowde4 apparently not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ...can you please check my updated code and let me know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this worked:

```
 boolean isOverLapped(Date newStartDate, Date newEndDate, Date existingStartDate, Date existingEndDate) throws NullPointerException{
            if (!((newEndDate.getTime() <= existingStartDate.getTime()) 
               || (newStartDate.getTime() >= existingEndDate.getTime()))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```